# Find the third point

Tags: math, drawing

I have 2 points `P1` and `P2`. I need to find the `P3`, in order that

- all points to be on the same line;
- `P3` should be at the distance `d` from the `P2` (away from `P1`)

I started a complicated system apparently hardly to resolve...
[image]

**PS.**

Vectorial answers is cool, but I use C# and don't know how to add vectors over there.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ - maybe you find better answers ;-)

Comment: You have only TWO points in a straight line that are at distance **d** of **P2** !!

Comment: @Svisstack: perhaps I should transfer this question there, but don 't know how.

Comment: Re vectors: Just break it up into x and y components, and operate on each.

Comment: @serhio, they will (or should) eat you up there. Ignacio gave the right answer. `|P2 - P1|  = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)`. That's plenty to get the job done.

Comment: I do not get the picture. P1, P1, and P3 are not colinear.

Comment: @aaronasterling: and for vector division how you do?

Comment: @serhio There's no such thing as vector division. `|P2 - P1|` is a number. Did you actually calculate it? To multiply a vector by a number, just multiply the components by that number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
P3 = P2 + d * ±(P2 - P1) / |P2 - P1|
```

**EDIT:**

Because shopping is easy:

```
mag = sqrt((P2x - P1x) ** 2 + (P2y - P1y) ** 2)
P3x = P2x + d * (P2x - P1x) / mag
P3y = P2y + d * (P2y - P1y) / mag
```

Comment: really I forgot the vector division...and why +- ?

Comment: ignacio, dude, could you suggest a non-vectorial answer please... :"( I should recognize do not be a math man.

Comment: Because there's two colinear points `d` away from `P2`: one away from `P1` (positive), and one towards `P1` (negative).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, how would we calculate the third point if angle was present at P2

Answer (score 2):

I have translated the code to Objective C

```
float distanceFromPx2toP3 = 1300.0;    

float mag = sqrt(pow((px2.x - px1.x),2) + pow((px2.y - px1.y),2));
float P3x = px2.x + distanceFromPx2toP3 * (px2.x - px1.x) / mag;
float P3y = px2.y + distanceFromPx2toP3 * (px2.y - px1.y) / mag;

CGPoint  P3 = CGPointMake(P3x, P3y);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked for me.  (for other searchers, the keywords that I was trying to find this answer with: Bresenham line projection to 3rd point)