# How to find the direction of the line in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, point, direction

Consider a line **AB** in Cartesian coordinates system. The length of the line is **d**.

**What I need:**

I want to draw an arrow in the point B, to represent the direction of the line.

**What I tried:**

[I found a point C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617387/how-can-i-find-the-points-in-a-line-objective-c), which is placed in the line AB, before some x points of B. Then I tried to find points (P & Q) with respect to the line CB in 90 degrees. But it does not work for me.

Refer this image:
[image]
Rather than doing this complex steps, is there any other way to find the direction of the line to draw the correct arrow in right direction?

Please remember the line may lie in any direction. All I have is, the point A & B only.

Comment: Point C can be right on top of Point A and still have a 90 degree angle.  You need to give us more information on how to determine where C should be.

Comment: Point C is does not a matter. This image describes the method I tried. Leave all those things and simply consider two points A & B. I need to draw an arrow in the point B. Is it now clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I do not think that the answer given in [How can I find the points in a line - Objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617387/how-can-i-find-the-points-in-a-line-objective-c/12618111#12618111) is too complex. You can make it *look* a bit nicer by using `CGPoint` instead of `(x, y)` pairs.
2. One input parameter is missing in your question: The desired size of the arrow, for example the distance from **C** to **B**.

That being said, the following computation should help you.

```
// Your points A and B:
CGPoint A = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
CGPoint B = CGPointMake(x2, y2);

// Vector from A to B:
CGPoint AB = CGPointMake(B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y);

// Length of AB == distance from A to B:
CGFloat d = hypotf(AB.x, AB.y);

// Arrow size == distance from C to B.
// Either as fixed size in points ...
CGFloat arrowSize = 10.;
// ... or relative to the length of AB:
// CGFloat arrowSize = d/10.;

// Vector from C to B:
CGPoint CB = CGPointMake(AB.x * arrowSize/d, AB.y * arrowSize/d);

// Compute P and Q:
CGPoint P = CGPointMake(B.x - CB.x - CB.y, B.y - CB.y + CB.x);
CGPoint Q = CGPointMake(B.x - CB.x + CB.y, B.y - CB.y - CB.x);
```

**P** is computed from **B** by subtracting the vector **CB** = (CB.x, CB.y) first and then adding the perpendicular vector (-CB.y, CB.x).